# jQuery Tablesorter: addParser depending on css class of th-element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have to add own parsers to the default ones of the Tablesorter plugin. It is really easy and a mind fact, because it is the only way to be flexible with the plugin.

Usually you tell the plugin which field should use a custom parser using the incremented id at table initialization, just like:

```
jQuery(".tablesorter").tablesorter({
    headers: {
        9: {
            sorter:'eur_currency' 
        }
    } 
});
```

Is it possible to link custom parser with css classes of th-elements? It would be nice, because the server-site program could decide wich parser is needet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just include the metadata plugin and add the sorter to the class name - see [this example](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-meta-parsers.html). So your markup would look something like this:

```
<th class="{ sorter : 'eur_currency' }">Currency</th>
```

---

So, I have a fork of this plugin on github and thought this would be nice to add. Check out [the demo page](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-class-name.html) and [download it from here](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter). It will work with custom parsers, so just set the class to:

```
<th class="sorter-eu_currency">Currency</th>
```

I didn't test if underscores "_" work in the class name, but I think they do.

Comment: Schema-Validator says: "The value '{ sorter : 'eur_currency' }' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:NMTOKENS'.".

Comment: Can't you change the doctype? When I [validate the example page](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftablesorter.com%2Fdocs%2Fexample-meta-parsers.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) I shared, it does have an error, but it's due to an empty ID

Comment: I used a [XML Schema-Validator](http://schneegans.de/sv/) not a lousy [DTD-Validator](http://validator.w3.org/). DTD-Validator cannot check the content of an attribute.

Comment: I've updated my answer... basically download the latest version.

Comment: It is working, just perfectly, even with underscores. Thx a lot @fudgey